# Why can MySQL not use a partial primary key index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, clustered-index

The MySQL documentation describing the [use of index extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-extensions.html), gives the following table as an example, followed by the query below:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    i1 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    i2 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    d DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (i1, i2),
    INDEX k_d (d)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE i1 = 3 AND d = '2000-01-01';
```

InnoDB internally will convert the index `k_d` to include the primary key at the end.  That is, the actual index `k_d` will be on `(d, i1, i2)`, three columns.

The documentation goes on to explain that (emphasis mine):

> The optimizer **cannot** use the primary key in this case because that comprises columns (i1, i2) and the query does not refer to i2. Instead, the optimizer **can** use the secondary index k_d on (d), and the execution plan depends on whether the extended index is used.

I am confused by the above statement.  First it says that `i1` is *not* enough to use the primary key index of two columns `(i1, i2)`.  Then, in the second sentence, it says that the index `k_d` on `(d, i1, i2)` *can* be used, despite that only `d` and `i1` are being used, with `i2` absent.

My general understanding of indices in MySQL, and in other flavors of SQL, is that a left portion of an index can be used if a subset of all columns in the index are present, starting from the left.

What is different about a primary key (clustered) index and a non clustered secondary index which allows the latter to use a partial index, but the former cannot?

Comment: I think the "cannot" is incorrect. If `k_d` is missing, the primary key will be user: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f9d6f/1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is partially inaccurate on the page you linked to.

Demo, run on MySQL 5.7.21:

```
mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > CREATE TABLE t1 (
    ->     i1 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ->     i2 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ->     d DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (i1, i2),
    ->     INDEX k_d (d)
    -> ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE i1 = 3 AND d = '2000-01-01';
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,k_d   | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

This query chooses the PRIMARY index, and you can see the `key_len` is 4, proving it will use only one of the 32-bit INT columns.

When using InnoDB tables, MySQL often prefers to use the PRIMARY index (the clustered index) because it's more efficient than using a secondary index.

Comment: This sounds like good detective work.  If you don't mind, I would like to wait a bit before awarding you the booty.

Comment: Agreed. Multiple Column Indexes can use the Leftmost Prefix which is demonstrated, oddly, in the same paragraph where it says it can't use `i1` in the primary index... Honestly that whole page could be cleaned up by just dropping the verbiage about the primary index as the page's topic only covers Extended Secondary Indexes.

Comment: [Documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on how a MultiColumn Index can use the Leftmost Prefix, which contradicts the paragraph OP is stuck on.

Comment: I cut the tech writers some slack. The MySQL manual is over 4000 pages long, and some of the topics are not understood even by the software developers.

Comment: Bill is right.  A prefix of either the primary index and the secondary index may be used here.  Which index is selected will be a cost-based decision by the query optimizer.  I have filed a documenation bug:  https://bugs.mysql.com/92347

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this

```
WHERE i1 = 3 AND d = '2000-01-01';
```

I prefer to *explicitly* say `INDEX(d, i1)` (or `INDEX(i1, d)`).  My rationale is that I am telling the reader that I thought about the indexes and realized that this was best for the query.  And it would be a "covering" index, hence a little faster.

Granted, the `INDEX(d)` you have *should* have been equivalent to `INDEX(d, i1, i2)`, which should have been used effectively and efficently.  As for why, I would guess an oversight in the Optimizer.

As for the documentation, there are a few poorly phrased places.  They welcome documentation critiques at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: See Bill Karwin's answer, which shows that in fact the optimizer _does_ use the covering index; there is no oversight AFAIK.  Agree with you about MySQL's documentation.  It has an open source flavor to it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - "Using index" == 'covering', "Using where" means something else.  See that Oystein wrote a doc bug report (Comment above).